# OpenLayers maximum DPI

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers.DOTS_PER_INCH (DPI) can be set to a value the developer chooses. Its default is 72 (from what I have researched) my question is, is there a maximum DPI that OpenLayers can be set to?

Comment: OpenLayers 3 has no DOTS_PER_INCH constant. Did you mean to tag this question with openlayers-2 instead?

Answer (score 1):

No, you could technically set it to max safe value of an integer in JS (9007199254740991).

All this number does is multiply against the resolution to determine map scale.